# unable to fetch website data for json elements for author description in json

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

```
package com.example.murarilal.volley;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue queue;
    private String url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        home();
    }
    public void home()
    {
        JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    Log.i("website content",response.getString("author"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
    }
```

**11-04 17:43:04.272 3687-3772/com.example.murarilal.volley E/EGL_emulation: tid 3772: eglSurfaceAttrib(1223): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
11-04 17:43:04.272 3687-3772/com.example.murarilal.volley W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9d77f060, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
11-04 17:43:04.276 3687-3772/com.example.murarilal.volley D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d704420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9d703460)
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for author
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at com.example.murarilal.volley.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:47)
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at com.example.murarilal.volley.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:41)
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
11-04 17:43:05.333 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
11-04 17:43:05.334 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
11-04 17:43:05.334 3687-3687/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
11-04 17:43:**

```
**"status": "ok",
"source": "the-next-web",
"sortBy": "latest",
-"articles": [
-{
"author": "Camille Charluet",
"title": "This tech festival is implanting microchips instead of using tickets",
"description": "Human microchipping has always been a pursuit reserved for those crazy guinea pig types excited for the dystopian future everyone else is dreading. As it turns out, 2017 seems to be ...",
"url": "https://thenextweb.com/distract/2017/11/01/tech-festival-implanting-microchips-instead-of-tickets/",
"urlToImage": "https://cdn0.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2017/11/wifi-hand-2-e1509553873488.png",
"publishedAt": "2017-11-01T18:10:26Z"
},
```

**

Comment: your error sys there is no value for author. ...seems like an easy fix.

Comment: author is inside of a jaon array object.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since author is inside of an array

```
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) object.get("articles");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).get("author"));
        }
```

That will print our your author.

Comment: youre welcome. next time you ask a question. dont just paste your code. give us a little more to go by. if you read your error, im pretty sure youd be able to figure out WHY your code wasnt working. that would probably also changed  your "question"

Answer (score 0):

The author field is not at the root of your json response, so you cannot get it using response.getString("author").

Instead, you'll need to iterate through the "articles" array of objects and get the author field from each article.